# Remove margin between divs

Tags: html, css

This question seems to have been answered a million times, and it seems to work a million times too. Not for me though. I would like to push together all the divs in

```css
.mainprogress {
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.mainprogress div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.detailprogress div {
  height: 100%;
}

.detailprogress .done {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.detailprogress .donelate {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.detailprogress .late {
  background-color: red;
}

.detailprogress .todo {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainprogress">
    <div class="detailprogress" style="height:100%;width:18%">
      <div class="done" style="width:58%"></div>
      <div class="late" style="width:41%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailprogress" style="height:35%;width:81%">
      <div class="done" style="width:73%"></div>
      <div class="todo" style="width:26%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/5/)

when fiddling enough with negative margins, it seems to start working at some point, but it feels terribly hackish. How do I get the elements to align to each other?

Comment: Yes, feel free to close/vote close (or should I delete myself? I feel there are some worthwhile answers here which would be a shame if they got lost)

Comment: Honestly, this question is asked at least once a day.  There are no answers here that aren't already attached to other duplicates of this problem.

Answer (score 14):

### Background:

Inline-block inserts a natural space between items.  In fact, it's essentially the width of a space if you were to hit the spacebar in your content, or even typing `&nbsp;` (an html markup space).  This space will be smaller or larger dependent on your **font size**.

There are several fixes to this problem, and I personally as well as many others consider this problem to be a sort of "bug" that needs fixing.  That said, all of the fixes for this are very "hackish" so to speak.  The solution you choose is up to your personal preference.

### Suggested Solution per your particular situation and code:

Simply switch over to using floats instead.  Instead of setting `display: inline-block;` do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/9/

```
.mainprogress div{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
```

### Other solutions:

(Note that in the JDFiddle solution using `margin-left` that the first div also moved left when it should not have done so.  To counteract this problem you will need to implement a class on that first div and make that -4 value 0 for that div alone.  Another solution, and my preferred solution, would be to use the `:first-child` [structural pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Structural_pseudo-classes) to select that first div.  It is more dynamic, and doesn't require HTML to be modified.

1. Fix the margin space by adding `margin-left: -4px;` -- http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/10/
2. Fix the space by shrinking the space using `font-size: 0px;`  -  http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/11/
3. Fix the space by deleting the line breaks between your div's (NOT RECOMMENDED - HARD TO READ) -- http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/12/
4. Fix the space by using `word-space: -.25em;` (See PavloMykhalov's comments below) -- http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/13/

***Note to other developers:  If there are other solutions to this please post below and I will add it above.  I feel like I'm missing a 5th way of fixing this...

Comment: `4. Fix the space by deleting the line breaks between your div's (NOT RECOMMENDED - HARD TO READ)` It may be hard for a developer to read, but that is beside the point. It 100% works and requires no CSS hacks.

Comment: Aligning all inline divs with a margin-right: 0px works PERFECTLY and as such (even with the original post that's claimed to have been a duplicate) this is STILL the BEST answer and it's Fall 2016. Thanks guy.

Answer (score 3):

The space is created because you've set the divs to "display: inline-block".

Read here how to fix:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I can't access CSS Tricks because of security policy. Can you please post a solution here?

Answer (score 3):

Try using floats instead of inline-block, wider support and it actually works:

http://jsfiddle.net/uhBW2/7/

```css
.mainprogress {
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mainprogress div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.detailprogress div {
  height: 100%;
}

.detailprogress .done {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.detailprogress .donelate {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.detailprogress .late {
  background-color: red;
}

.detailprogress .todo {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainprogress">
    <div class="detailprogress" style="height:100%;width:18%">
      <div class="done" style="width:58%"></div>
      <div class="late" style="width:41%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailprogress" style="height:35%;width:81%">
      <div class="done" style="width:73%"></div>
      <div class="todo" style="width:26%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Also, note the overflow hidden on the .mainprogress element. This causes the container to become the same height as it's floating children (same as a css clear: both; fix)

Comment: the overflow: hidden; is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to Add `float:left` to all the Elements that you need to push together like below:

```
.mainprogress {
    height:60px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.mainprogress div{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.detailprogress div {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.detailprogress .done {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    float:left;

}
.detailprogress .donelate {
    background-color:lightpink;
    float:left;
}
.detailprogress .late {
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
.detailprogress .todo {
    background-color:green
        float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is very redundent.  He only needs to add float: left to the selector that has display: inline-block;  That rule should also be deleted if you use float: left.